# Selenium - Files not downloading to Jenkins directory when the download is initiated from UI

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

Hoping someone can help me here,

**Scenario:** I am,

1. Navigating to the page where there is a download icon
2. Clicking on Download icon
3. .pdf file starts downloading to my project directory

Note: There is no confirmation message displayed during download and as soon as the download icon is clicked the file gets downloaded

Observed: When running the test case locally(from mvn command and also from testng) it seems to be working and downloading the file to my directory.

However the same case doesn't seem to be working in Jenkins. The file is not downloaded to Jenkins Directory.

Local: Windows Machine
Jenkins: Linux
Browser: Chrome

**Paths configured:**

```
String parentDirectoryPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");

String testExecutionDownloadFilesFolderPath = parentDirectoryPath + File.separator + "TestingExecutionResult" +File.separator+"DownloadedFiles"+ File.separator;
```

So, Basically the file gets downloaded in "**DownloadedFiles**" Folder that's present in my Project directory.

I am printing the Jenkins path where the download is supposed to happen and it seems to be pointing correctly:

```
2021-07-15 08:02:13 INFO UI_PAGE - FILEPATH===> /var/jenkins_home/workspace/PROJECT_UI/TestingExecutionResult/DownloadedFiles/
```

The same case runs successfully but the file is not downloaded in the Jenkins directory.

Please guide me if I am missing anything here.

Snippet for File download:

```
 int beforeDownload = FilesAndDirectoriesHelper.getNoOfFilesInDirectory(
            downloadPath);
    log.info("Total Files before Download: " + beforeDownload);
    JSExecutorHelper.clickOnWebElement(driver, downloadIcon);
    log.info("Clicked download icon for entry....");
    //Sleep is being used to wait for the download to complete
    TimeWaitHandling.threadSleepDelay(10000);

    int afterDownload = FilesAndDirectoriesHelper.getNoOfFilesInDirectory(
            downloadPath);
    log.info("Total Files after Download Start: " + afterDownload);
```

**downloadPath** - Path provided above (testExecutionDownloadFilesFolderPath).

```
//This method is used to return the no. of files present in given folder
public static int getNoOfFilesInDirectory(String directoryFilePath) {

    try {
        File directory = new File(directoryFilePath);
        if(directory!=null) {

            File[] files = directory.listFiles();
            return files.length;
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, you need to set your download path in the browser config.

**In Chrome:**

```
String parentDirectoryPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String downloadFilepath = parentDirectoryPath+"/downloads/";
APP_LOGS.debug("Chrome Download path set to: "+downloadFilepath);
File downloadFolder = new File(downloadFilepath);
if (!downloadFolder.exists()){
      downloadFolder.mkdir();
 }
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
prefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

**In Firefox:**

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", downloadFilepath)
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-gzip")

FirefoxOptions option = new FirefoxOptions();
option.setProfile(profile);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(option);
```

**Note: Please provide more information about the issue. Like browser you are using, logic you have implemented.**

Answer (score 0):

If Chrome is running in a Docker container you'd want to read up on Bind Mounts in the Docker documentation.